Open Google Tasks in separate window from Google Calendar with Google Chrome
In Google Workspaces I can open Google Calendar with URL https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r and Google Tasks with URL https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/tasks.

I have created a Chrome app for Google Calendar (https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r) using "Menu > Save and Share > Create Shortcut". But when I do the same steps for Google Tasks (https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/tasks) it creates the same app with Google Calendar icon. And because of that the Calendar and Tasks are same window forcing me to use Cmd + ` to switch between Calendar and Tasks. I want a separate window for Google Tasks so that I can use Cmd + Tab. Is it possible?
